Chasing diagrams of chain complexes which are pointwise projective

For context this question arose in a simple K-theory computation, where I wish to show that the inclusion of the category of bounded degreewise projective chain complexes into the category of bounded perfect chain complexes satisfies the approximation property needed to use the approximation theorem. See for example exercise 9.2 in chapter II of the K-book freely available online. But the context isn't too important, and this question should only require relatively simple homological algebra. 
We work throughout in some abelian category. Suppose we are given a bounded complex $M_\bullet$, a bounded degreewise projective complex $Q_\bullet$ such that there is a quasi isomorphism $f: Q_\bullet \to M_\bullet$ and we are given another bounded degreewise projective complex $P_\bullet$ with an arbitary map $g: P_\bullet\to M_\bullet$. Our goal is to find a bounded degreewise projective module $R_\bullet $ such that we can factor $g: P_\bullet\to M_\bullet$ as a composition $P_\bullet\hookrightarrow R_\bullet\xrightarrow{\simeq} M_\bullet$, where the first map is pointwise an inclusion and the second map is a quasi-isomoprhism. 
My main idea has been to use the fact that the complexes are bounded to hope for a proof by induction. Indeed by taking a large enough (or small enough, but this is less promising) index, $M_i$ is $0$, in which case we can construct a map $P_i\to Q_i$. Then assume some induction and diagram chase allows us to construct a chain map $P_\bullet\to Q_\bullet$, which makes the obvious diagram commute. Then we get the desired result via mapping cylinders. 
However the diagram chase seems more or less pointless, and so I am wondering whether one should use another strategy to get the desired factorization. However I don't see what other method as a chance at working... 
Any help is appreciated, thank you so much for your help.

Do you need commutativity up to chain homotopy, or strict commutativity?

The composition $P_\bullet\hookrightarrow R_\bullet\xrightarrow{\simeq}M_\bullet$ has to genuinely equal $g: P_\bullet\to M_\bullet$.

Right. This is strange, it feels like it should be easy but all factorisation results of this ilk I'm aware of work up to homotopy. For example, there is a factorisation of $g$ through the given $Q\simeq M$ ... up to homotopy
